# Laravel - How to Customize Sweetalert2 on delete

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

  $goal = AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id);
  $goal->delete();
  Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal deleted successfully.');
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

blade

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="deleteTag({{ $goal->id }})">
     Delete
</button>
<form id="delete-form-{{ $goal->id }}" action="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.destroy',$goal->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

During delete, I want to customize the message:

Are you sure you want to delete $goal->goal_title

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function deleteTag(id) {
    var name = $(this).data('goal_title');
    swal({
        title: 'Delete',
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete "+name+"!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('delete-form-'+id).submit();
        } else if (
            // Read more about handling dismissals
            result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            swal(
                'Cancelled',
                'Your data is safe :)',
                'error'
            )
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

When I added the code above, it displays it as I have written it.

> Are you sure you want to delete undefined!

How do I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere. The code you have here `"Are you sure you want to delete "+name+"!"` would not display that behaviour.

Comment: @miken32 -  Sorry the error is:   Are you sure you want to delete undefined!

Comment: That would make sense. What is `$(this).data('goal_title')`? Where do you expect that to come from?

Comment: @miken32 - 'goal_title' is a field in the table appraisal_goals. I am expecting some like :     Are you sure you want to delete Appraisal2020.   Appraisal2020 is one of the data in the field. THat means it is to confirm whether you want to delete the selected field as in $goal->goal_title

Comment: But why did you expect `$(this).data('goal_title')` to get that information? I guess step one is "what is `this`?" And then step two is "what does the `data` method do?"

Comment: that variable will never be filled in because you don't provide data attributes named `goal_title` on the button element, and I think, a practical way is, by adding one more parameter to the delete_tag function for `goal_title`, `onclick="deleteTag({{ $goal->id }}, {{$goal->title_OrWhateverYouNamedIt}})`, and you can retrieve that in your function

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung - How do I add goal_title to onclick="deleteTag({{ $goal->id }}).   Can you give a sample

Comment: @mikefolu just pass the second parameter to your `deleteTag` function on `onClick` event like what I say above, then retrieve that inside your function `` function deleteTag(id,goal_title) { const name = goal_title; // here you can retrieve it, and use as you wish }``

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung - When I added this    onclick="deleteTag({{ $goal->id }}, {{$goal->goal_title }})     I got this error         Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @mikefolu just read that error reference, you missing `)` :)